# Get a list of user ID's that have shared a photo on a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I need to get a list of user facebook ID's that have shared a photo on my facebook fan page. I've put the id of the photo through the graph api explorer but all you get is the comments, likes and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible, unless they shared the photo using your app, then you should have stored that action.  :)

Comment: Thanks, looks like they're developing too fast again

Comment: yeah, you really should track your own app's actions in order to run good statistics.  It's a fairly easy SQL insert on your side to store the info on each item as it happens in your app.

Comment: ye its not through an app, its just off the wall. Pretty sure facebook frown upon doing what were doing but it builds up the likes pretty fast. but i get what your saying, google analytics custom events would work pretty well for that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  Why would Facebook frown upon your app for tracking its own user activity statistics?  The only way for your app devs to improve performance of an app and ui designers to make a better user interface is to monitor how people use your app.